# Sql I have to compare the aggregates values of Group by column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

let say we have 2 tables:
Table1:GroupQueue
group to queue mapping:

```
group   queue
G1       Q1
G1       Q2
G1       Q3
G2       Q2
G2       Q4
```

and agent to queue mapping:

Table3:AgentQueue

```
agent   queue
A1       Q1
A1       Q2
A1       Q3
A1       Q4
A2       Q2
A3       Q1
A3       Q2
A3       Q4
A3       Q5
```

we want to map agent with a group only if he has all the queues assigned to the group:
Final Output:

```
group   agent
G1  A1
G2  A1
G2  A3
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? Those are two very different database products.

Comment: read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to do this is by constructing an inner join between the two tables and ordering by agent, and then queue.

```
queues=# select t1.group, t2.agent, t2.queue from groupqueue as t1

inner join agentqueue as t2 on t1.queue=t2.queue order by agent, queue;


     group | agent | queue 
    -----+-------+-------
     G1  | A1    | Q1
     G2  | A1    | Q2
     G1  | A1    | Q2
     G1  | A1    | Q3
     G2  | A1    | Q4
     G2  | A2    | Q2
     G1  | A2    | Q2
     G1  | A3    | Q1
     G2  | A3    | Q2
     G1  | A3    | Q2
     G2  | A3    | Q4
    (11 rows)
```

From the above, we can see that Agent A1 fits the criteria, as he belongs to Q1, Q2 and Q3 which form part of G1, while Q2 and Q4 form part of G2.

Agent A2 only belongs to Q2, while Agent A3 belongs to G2 as he matches Q2 and Q4.

Comment: No,It won;t work . Agent A2 won't be there in output . A2 don't have all queue which come under any groups

Answer (score 0):

You need a `CROSS` join of `GroupQueue` to the distinct `agent`s and a `LEFT` join to `AgentQueue` and aggregation:

```
SELECT g.group, d.agent
FROM GroupQueue g 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT agent FROM AgentQueue) d
LEFT JOIN AgentQueue a ON a.queue = g.queue AND a.agent = d.agent 
GROUP BY g.group, d.agent
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(a.queue)
ORDER BY g.group, d.agent;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=da88d1f56afcb4b8ad55c5a5cdd8ac0b)

Answer (score 0):

its not a correct way but its worked

````
select 
 g.group , 
 listagg(distinct g.queue ,',')within group (order by g.group , g.queue  ) as queues  
 from genesys.GroupQueue  g 
 group by 
 g.group  
)  ,
aqentq as(
 select    
 a.agent  ,
 listagg(distinct a.queue,',')within group (order by g.group ,a.queue) as queues 
 from genesys.AgentQueue  a 
 left join   genesys.GroupQueue g on a.queue=g.queue
 group by  
 a.agent   
)
select  
 g.group,  
 a.agent 
from groupq g
join aqentq a on a.queues like '%'+g.queues+'%'  ```
````